# Moving directories without overwriting the files

Tags: linux, mv

In Linux, I have a folder, say `ABC` and in this folder I have sub folders `A`, `B` and `C`

These folders can have files, for example, folder `A` can have, `A1`, `A2`, `A3` etc.

I want to move all these folders to another folder say `A2Z`

Now, this new folder `A2Z` might or might not already have folders `A`, `B` and `C`. I want to move the folders which don't exist, and *append the contents* of the folders which do exist.

Comment: Why close? If the solution already exists can you direct me to one?

Comment: This answer over on SuperUser should help you out
http://superuser.com/questions/37137/moving-files-on-linux-appending-existing-directories-in-destination

Answer (score 2):

Use interactive move which makes sure to prompt you in the case of a similar file/directory in the destination

```
mv --interactive
```

Or if you don't want to move the files already present in the destination directory, then the following should be able to do that for you

```
for f in $(find /src/dir -type f); do target=/dest/dir/$(basename $f); if [[ ! -e $target ]]; then mkdir -p $(dirname $target);mv $f $target; fi; done
```

Another option will be to set the --no-clobber flag which will raise an error if you try to overwrite an existing file by output redirection

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/37137/moving-files-on-linux-appending-existing-directories-in-destination) over on our sister site [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) you can do

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files src/ dest/
```

Note that I've recommended this question be migrated there, so this question, and my answer, might soon disappear!